# postgresql jsonb case insensitive query

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE cityData
(
  item character varying,
  data jsonb
);
```

it contains values like

```
ITEM        DATA
test1       [{"rank":"1", "city":"New York"},{"rank":"3", "city":"Sidney"}] 
test2       [{"rank":"2", "city":"NEW YORK"},{"rank":"4", "city":"New Delhi"}]
```

I need to get number of distinct json objects where city is 'New York'
I am using the following query

```
SELECT  * FROM   cityData t
WHERE ( data @> '[{"city":"New York"}]')
and t.item ilike '%test%';
```

But this query outputs test1 row. I need to make the query case insensitive so that `data @> '[{"city":"New York"}]'` matches both `New York` and `NEW YORK`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
where lower(data::text)::jsonb @> lower('[{"city":"New York"}]')::jsonb
```

Comment: will it be efficient to cast to text then again cast to jsonb?

Comment: @ranjan Do not use json for structured data.

Comment: Don't use json for structured data? What do you mean by that?

Comment: @dwanderson: structured data is data that is easily normalized.

Answer (score 5):

With PostgreSQL 12+, case-insensitive matches can be done using `@?` operator and a [`jsonpath` query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH). Following the example in question, your clause might looks something along the lines of:

```sql
where data @? '$[*].city like_regex "(?i)^NEW YORK$"'
```

This can be significantly faster without building specific case-insensitive indexes, as opposed to casting JSONB to string and back to use `lower()`.

Comment: Would you happen to know if a similar syntax can be used when the path itself might have different cases? In the example above there would be rows with `"CITY"` instead of `"city"`...

Comment: @JulienGenestoux It was a while ago that I worked on this but seems doubtful. If you don’t know what keys there are, maybe you can extract the actual keys using `json_object_keys()` function listed in the docs (the link in the answer) and then work with that. Not idea how it would look in the end though…