# postgresql jsonb case insensitive query with index

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, where-clause, jsonb

I was looking for a way to make a case insensitive query, and I found it here ([postgresql jsonb case insensitive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949620/postgresql-jsonb-case-insensitive-query)), more precisely with a query like this : `select ... where upper(data::text)::jsonb @> upper('[{"city":"New York"}]')::jsonb`

However, I can't seem to find enough information about how to create an index to be used by such a query.

```
where data::text @> '[{"city":"New York"}]'
```

works perfectly with a GIN index

```
CREATE INDEX i1 ON mytable USING gin(data);
```

but the upper(...) function will trigger a full scan which costs too much.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to index the complete expression:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tab USING gin ((upper(data::text)::jsonb));
```