# How to query a JSONField comprising a list of values in DJANGO

Tags: python, json, django, orm, django-jsonfield

I am using `JSONField` to store the configuration parameter(user_types) as a list as follows:

```
["user_type1", "user_type2", "user_type3"]
```

How to query to filter elements of type "user_type1"? The following query is not working:

```
rows=ConfigUserTable.objects.filter(user_types__in=["user_type1"])
```

Thanks

Comment: Which DB backend are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`__contains` works. Adding an answer as the current one is a guess with errors, and this isn't covered in the Django docs. Also there is a twist for `__icontains`.

```
>>> for i in MyModel.objects.all():
>>>     i.aliases = None  # JSONField(null=True)
>>>     i.save()
>>> i.aliases = ['a', 'b', 'abc']
>>> i.save()
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(aliases__contains='a').exists()
True
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(aliases__contains='ab').exists()
False
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(aliases__contains='abc').exists()
True
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(aliases__contains='A').exists()
False
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(aliases__icontains='A').exists()
True
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(aliases__icontains='AB').exists()
True
```

That last result surprised me because the `i`  in `__icontains` usually means case-insentive, but in this case it means string entries are case-insensitive and partially matched.

This is [because Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#escaping-percent-signs-and-underscores-in-like-statements) uses `LIKE` for `i`-prefixed lookups:

```
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(aliases__contains='ab').exists()
False
>>> print(MyModel.objects.filter(aliases__contains='ab').query)
...WHERE "metadata_livelihoodcategory"."aliases" @> '"ab"'...

>>> MyModel.objects.filter(aliases__icontains='ab').exists()
True
>>> print(MyModel.objects.filter(aliases__icontains='ab').query)
...WHERE UPPER("metadata_livelihoodcategory"."aliases"::text) LIKE UPPER(%ab%)...
```

Use of `LIKE` here is a tiny bit hacky, but very useful, and if I had to choose, I'd choose this behaviour.

However, look again at that `__icontains` SQL:

```
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(aliases__icontains='["A", "AB').exists()
True
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(aliases__icontains='", "').exists()
True
```

Better SQL is possible ([thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37950045/1308967)):

```
>>> select count(*) from app_mymodel where
...     upper(aliases::text)::jsonb @> upper('"AB"')::jsonb;
0
>>> select count(*) from app_mymodel where 
...     upper(aliases::text)::jsonb @> upper('"A"')::jsonb;
1
>>> select count(*) from app_mymodel where 
...     upper(aliases::text)::jsonb @> upper('", "')::jsonb;
0
```

How would you name the lookup for this "a list contains a string which case-insensitive contains"? `__iccontains`? Postgresql only?

One last thing. `__contains` does not seem to work when within a dict.

```
>>> i.aliases = {"types": ["user_type1", "user_type2", "user_type3"]}
>>> i.save()
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(aliases__contains="types").exists()
True
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(aliases__types__contains="user_type1").exists()
False
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(aliases__types__icontains="user_type1").exists()
False
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(aliases__types__0__contains="user_type1").exists()
False
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(aliases__types__0__icontains="user_type1").exists()
False
```

Django 4.2.7 on Postgresql. `aliases` is a standard `JSONField` with `null=True`.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `contains` lookup, which is overridden on `JSONField`. For example, the following may work:

```py
ConfigUserTable.objects.filter(user_types__contains="user_type1")
```

However, this might depend on how you are storing JSON data in the field. If you are storing the data as a dict, querying on that key will certainly work. I.e. data in this format in the field `user_types`:

```json
{"types": ["user_type1", "user_type2", "user_type3"]}
```

could be queried like so:

```py
ConfigUserTable.objects.filter(user_types__types__contains="user_type1")
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#std:fieldlookup-jsonfield.contains

Comment: Your first query does work. Your second query does not (which surprised me too). `contains` searches keys of a dict, so `ConfigUserTable.objects.filter(user_types__contains="types")` would return the instance. Props for explicitly using the "may work" qualifier so people know you're educated guessing though.